# Generated files on Android not visible on PC by USB connect? | Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, mobile

The files generated on Android are not visible on the PC by USB connect. However, after a restart the files do show on the PC.

Afterwards, if I have generated another new file, I then have to restart my mobile again to make the file visible.

This is my relevant piece of code:

```java
File exportDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath(), "/storage/data/Scan_CSV_FILE");
if (!exportDir.exists()) {

    exportDir.mkdirs();
}
String filename = FileHeander + File_NoET.getText().toString() + ".csv";
File file = new File(exportDir, filename);
try {
    file.createNewFile(); 
    CSVWriter csvWrite = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(file));
    Cursor curCSV = sqliteDb.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM table", null);
    String arrHeander[] = {"filed1", "filed2", "filed3","filed4"};
    csvWrite.writeNext(arrHeander);
    while (curCSV.moveToNext()) {
        //Which column you want to exprort
        String arrStr[] = {curCSV.getString(1), curCSV.getString(2), curCSV.getString(3), curCSV.getString(4)};
        csvWrite.writeNext(arrStr);
    }
csvWrite.close();
curCSV.close();
Toast.makeText(this, "CSV Downloaded !!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

How can I fix the issue so that newly generated files are immediately visible and avoiding having to restart each time?

Answer (score 0):

IT'S COMMON FOR CERTAIN MODELS OF PHONES,

> My `Samsung galaxy xx` behaves like this(a bit old phone `android version-5.1`)

> But my other phone-new model does not behave like this(`android version-9`)

> You need not Restart every time-You can plug out the wire and plug-in (USB wire), if it works or not don't worry, because it's common-EVEN IN MY MOBILE IF I RECEIVE A FILE IN WHATSAPP I NEED TO PLUG-OUT AND IN USB CABLE

> if it does not work try another mobile IT WILL WORK `if` IT WAS A MOBILE WITH GREATER VERSION/NEWER MODEL.

> P. S I am typing this with a greater experience of my old phone

Comment: Thank you will check and let you know in comment 

Comment: pls reply if it work mark as solution(tick)